# Add a custom button in the Tabbar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbar

Is there any way to add a custom button in the tabbar of Xamarin.Forms, like it's seeable on the mock below?

Thanks in advance.
Cue.

[image: Mock Screen Shot]

Comment: Not with the default tabbed page. Only way to get this, is by creating your own custom renderer for tabbar.

Comment: In the custom renderer you would add this button between the regular tabbar items or is it about overriding a style of an desired tabbar item?

Comment: If it's for iOS too, I guess you want to redesign it yourself completely, not sure you can get this functionality with build in tabbar.

Comment: actually i want to create the custom tabbar for Android as well as for iOS

Comment: yeah that's why I said I guess you'll need to render one yourself! instead of using the build in ones...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can use relative layout to add the tabs in Xaml,
If you need any coding help let me know I'll help you to design this layout.

Comment: Thank you @Sumit Pathak that would be very interesting to see how the xaml looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while looking into implementing a very similar tab bar. There is one other option I've found to do this without writing those hefty custom renders yourself. Check out [Sharpnado](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms). It provides a variety of possible customizations for a Xamarin.Forms tab bar.

There is also a [blog post](https://www.sharpnado.com/pure-xamarin-forms-tabs/) on implementing a few options, complete with sample code you can clone.